# Restrict Users To create Account Teams on Account object

Tags: validation-rule

only system administrators should be able to add account team member in account object. remaining users should not have the permission to add account teams.

how can we achieve this using validation rule.

Comment: What have you tried so far that hasn't worked for you? Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post what you've written so far and where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions about real problems or errors with our code.

Comment: Account object contains Account teams as a related list where all the users can able to add the account team members.

Comment: how can we restrict that only system admins can add the account team members through validation rule

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because Account Teams do not have the typical features like Workflow Rules, Triggers, Validation Rules, etc. You can remove the related list from the page layout, but this won't restrict using alternative means (e.g. Data Loader) from modifying this table. You'll want to vote for [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YR8IAAW) to allow triggers on the ATM table, but at the moment, there are no plans to implement this.

One workaround that we came up with on one project was to create a custom ATM table, attach a trigger to it to insert/update/delete ATM records, and we wrote a scrubbing system (basically a Scheduleable class that called a Batchable class hourly) to delete any unauthorized ATM records. It worked out pretty well, but it was still possible to sneak in unauthorized records for up to an hour (but this required API access, as the standard ATM related list was removed from all layouts).

Answer (score 1):

Account teams are a master-detail style relationship and as such the permissions for adding/editing them are inherited so if you have permissions to edit the account, you also have permissions to modify account teams.

You cannot prevent this via a validation rule primarily because SFDC doesn't allow creating validation rules on the account team object.

Others have tried to do triggers or install app packages but unfortunately that doesn't work. Even the link in @Ajay Dubedi answer specifically says that there was an error when trying to use the Declarative Rollups for Lookups app:

> Gave the Lookup Rollup approach a shot but ran into issues when
>   deploying the child trigger:
>
> **triggers/dlrs_AccountTeamMemberTrigger.trigger (Line: 4: Column:42) :
>   SObject type does not allow triggers: AccountTeamMember**

I even went it to see if it was possible to remove the button for adding members from the page layout so you could try to have an admin only layout with the button on it; however, the account team related list is not customizable.

The only way I can think to accomplish this is to completely re-write the account detail page in visualforce (which usually isn't too hard with the <apex:detail> and <apex:relatedList>) and recode just the account team related list to remove the button. This should allow admins to configure the layout the same way they usually would with a few limitations (like they wont beable to re-arrange the order of related lists or decide which lists appear on the page). While allowing you to control who can and can't modify the account team. Then just use your new vf page as the "view" page for the account object.

It'll take some work to accomplish so you may want to ask your self how important is this effort? Will simply training your users not to modify the team work for your needs or is this something that needs to be strictly enforced?

### Update

After reading SFDCFox's answer, I think this is a middle ground approach. It'll take less work than SFDCFox's approach but also has a few limits that his approach won't have.