# Prevent Account Team modification by Users

Tags: account-teams

We maintain Account Teams programmatically based on an external system. Accordingly, we need to remove User ability to manually modify Account Teams for their Accounts.

But we cannot Trigger on AccountTeamMember.

For now, we have removed the standard Account Team related list from the Account's Page Layout. We also have a custom object functioning as the controlling entity to mirror itself onto the AccountTeamMember table periodically. I've seen [others](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218005/restrict-users-to-create-account-teams-on-account-object) recommend a similar pattern as well.

I am not thrilled about this solution. Is there a better way, or is this best practice for now?

Comment: If you can [wait until Winter '20](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YR8IAAW), you will likely get to see a trigger on AccountTeamMember.

Comment: oh, a feature "commit" that is excellent (safe harbor, I get it) good call though, thanks @JayantDas! add as answer? I will close.

Comment: At least you can wait for few more months before going the custom route altogether.

Comment: This is now available in [the Winter '20 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_sales_feature_core_accounts.htm) with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, there's no straight forward way to do so. You will need to resort to custom options. However before taking that route, you may like to wait until Winter '20. We may most likely see a trigger on `AccountTeamMember` with Winter '20 *#safeharbor*.

This is mentioned on Latest comment from Salesforce on the related idea [Allow triggers on Account Team Member Object](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YR8IAAW).

Comment: And also, validation rules. Which could help with this use case and avoid code.